# Flicker when tapping on - button when table view is in edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using a custom class which is subclassing UITableViewCell. Now, when tableview goes in edit mode, I adjust the UIComponents on the cell inside layoutSubviews of my custom class. Now, when user tap on the "-" button the layoutSubviews get called once again and the UIComponents on the cell again repositions themselves which causes a weird UI flicker. I tried with below code in layoutSubviews but then UIComponents on the cell does not reposition themselves when user tap on edit and table comes in edit mode. Is there any graceful way to handle this.

```
if (self.editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found this property which is set when user tap on the - button to show the delete button:

```
self.showingDeleteConfirmation
```